# how to create and delete dynamics <div> with several components Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

My goal is to have a structure of several rows created dynamically with Boostrap, look like a table and looks like if a `<html>` table structure will solve my problem but is not like this. Till now I can add succesfully with the add button every row (`<div>`) with all components inside. All components are correct and individually created. But I will like to have the option to delete a row. For that reason I added to each row the delete button, in the case that wanted to be deleted.

Only the first row doesn't have a delete button because by default should be at least one row visibel. With the shown below code I just can delete the second row and is only working correct (deleting all cliked rows) if I add to the code a alert message. For me this is very strange and I can not see the problem

```
$("#var_conteiner a").click(function(){//var_conteiner general div with the row structure

                var current_dinamic_id = $(this).attr('id');
                var arr_tmpid = current_dinamic_id.split("");

                if(arr_tmpid[0]=='d'){
                    var current_del_btn_id = $(this).attr('id');
                    var tmp_del_id = current_del_btn_id.split("del");
                    alert(tmp_del_id[1]);
                    $("#conteiner_"+tmp_del_id[1]).remove();
                }

        });
```

And the structure per row looks like this:

```
<div id="var_conteiner">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <input type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <input type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <a><img src="public/images/del.png" width="16" height="16"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/4ra83scr/)

Comment: the first problem I'm seeing is that you are trying to get the `id` (first line of code in your click function), but the `this` refers to your `<a>` element, which does not have an `id`

Comment: also, you're using an `id` for each `row`-structure. This isn't good practice, considering an `id` should be unique and cannot be used more then once on the same page.

Comment: Hi @Jorrex Thx for answer me. I created every id dynamically also. Every <a> has a different id and in relation with this id is the row parent who this row below

Comment: except in your example code, the only element that has an id, is your top-parent div. I posted an answer below which does the trick with a single line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to point out two things about your code:
 1. An `id` is unique and cannot be copied over to other elements. Better use a class when using multiple elements which'll have the same functionality.
 2. Your code can be minified by a single line. Check out the snippet I inserted into this post.

```js
function bindEvents() {
  $(".remove").unbind("click").click(function() { //var_conteiner general div with the row structure
    checkContainers($(this));
  });

  $(".add").unbind("click").click(function() {
    $(this).parents("div.container").clone().appendTo("body");
    bindEvents(); //bind events after adding a new "row"
  });
}

function checkContainers(el) {
  if ($("div.container").length > 1) {
    el.parents("div.container").remove();
  }
}

bindEvents(); //execute it for the first time
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <input type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <button class="add">
          Add
        </button>
        <button class="remove">
          Remove
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**EDIT**
I edited the code a bit, because you wanted not being able to remove a "row" when there was only one.

Comment: Is this what you required? Or does it have to be with dynamically added id's?

Comment: Thx!! Is exactly what I wanted TJHX!!